# how can I get edittextchanged values in a string array in customize listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I can fetch the item names from a database and append them to an edit text. How do I store changed values in an edit text? I want them stored in a string array.

```
          public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
public String editnewmainmenu, menuname,edittext;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, itemcode;
public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    View vi = convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);

    EditText text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);


    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);
    text.append(itemnames[position]);
    String edittext=text.toString();
    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {            
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(text.length() > 0) {
                String newName = text.getText().toString();
            } else if(text.length() == 0) {

            }
        }
      });            
    //Toast.makeText(Context, edittext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return vi;
}
```

}

I take all item names from my MySql database on android mobile and append them to the editext. The admin can change item names (more than one) and on change, it shall replace the previous item names. I want to update them.

Comment: i think u want to update name into database??

Comment: ya sir.. i want update ..please tell me the solution. i struct past one week ..please tell me

Comment: OK just read unique id from that row from you reads name, after editing name in edit-text, fire update query on database with read unique id of that row.

Comment: i want get after change values of edittext

Comment: ya i want update itemnames to the database . know i want get what are the change editable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do somethin like dis

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {            
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(myEditText.length() > 0) {
                String newName = myEditText.getText().toString();
            } else if(myEditText.length() == 0) {

            }
        }
      });
```

after this event update your database...

Comment: please see my code once . i can update my full code.. please see tell me now

Comment: I've edited ur code to jus refresh this screen on ur system so u can see the change

Comment: ya . i can get first time only it prints one time next time i can change any thing it print 2 times. why it print 2 times please tell me

Comment: I think, this event will be called as many time as the text change appears in EditText, but i m not sure, i wil check it after some times and tell u later